# How make snowflake dml faster?

Tags: performance, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, query-optimization, database-performance, dml

Snowflake is a read-optimized database, so read operations are fast, but write operations may take time. This is what is happening right now in my project, as Snowflake is also used as OLTP db (don't know why). The transactional stored procedures, which do a lot of inserts/updates/merges take longer than the client can afford to wait.
Any tips, as to how we can make the dmls in Snowflake faster? any pointers will be great. thanks.

Comment: It's actually also really fast for writes, if you write in bulk. So perhaps more of what is happening is you are writing across many partitions so having large write costs (as a ratio of the little of your row counts) on updates. Also if you are writing to the same table on different sessions (concurrently) you will stall most other writes. So really avoid concurrent writes to the same table.

Comment: If you are doing INSERT commands, with 10MB of SQL text, (or UPDATE with large SQL text commands) you will also have horrible performance as the compile times for these commands will be very silly, again, new data should (as bulk as possible) COPY INTO'd some form of temp/transient tables, and then MERGED into destination tables, imho (and given that is an opinion, it implies there question as it currently is, is poorly worded, and likely will be closed).

Comment: well the internet has corrected, me. https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/faster-cheaper-file-ingestion-ron-dunn%3FtrackingId=JDbt6I4b4HevwG36z4LyIA%253D%253D/?trackingId=JDbt6I4b4HevwG36z4LyIA%3D%3D

Comment: My first question would be what sort of performance you are looking for? If you need the performance of an OLTP system on single/few records then that's unlikely to be achievable with Snowflake (at least until they release the new Unistore/hybrid tables). While you may be able to speed up your DML it's also likely to be costly - for example you would need to keep your warehouse(s) running permanently as waiting for a warehouse to start up is going to kill the performance

Comment: @NickW mentioned a good point. When you kick off any DML, it has to start a warehouse and write the code. DML operation of 1row in every 1 min, will be much slower than 10000 rows at a time and then a gap of 1 hour. Its good for bulk operatin. You can also try to keep a X-small warehouse and keep it up always and try. But its still can be an issue because, system has to look for different partitions to do the DML.

Comment: As Simeon and NickW noted, Snowflake is not optimized for OLTP work. It is a columnar database whereas OLTP tends to be row based. Having said that, I have a bit of an off the wall suggestion that may help but not fully resolve the speed issue: change your process to perform updates to dynamic tables and use the SCD approach in this article with your base tables. https://medium.com/snowflake/slowly-changing-dimensions-with-dynamic-tables-d0d76582ff31